# VisualStudio2019のCHtmlViewでGoogleMapを表示するとエラーが出る

Tags: mfc

以下のサイトを参考に、VisualStudio2019でCHtmlViewを用いたアプリケーションを作成しました。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/mfc/reference/creating-a-web-browser-style-mfc-application?view=vs-2019
ウィザードで作成したアプリのOnInitialUpdateを以下のように修正して実行すると、

```
// 修正前
void CMFCApplication2View::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CHtmlView::OnInitialUpdate();

    Navigate2(_T("http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualc/default.aspx"),nullptr, nullptr);
}

// 修正後
void CMFCApplication2View::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CHtmlView::OnInitialUpdate();

    // 引数が3つだとビルドエラーになるので、1つに変更
    Navigate2(_T("https://maps.google.co.jp/"));
}
```

キャプチャのように、互換表示の警告が出ます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

IEの互換表示は無効にしており、WindowsUpdateも実施済みです。
尚、PCにはChromeもインストールしており、こちらが規定ブラウザという設定です。

この警告が出た後、スクリプトエラーが何度も出ますが、一応地図の閲覧はできます。
警告やスクリプトエラーが出ないようにしたいのですが、何をすればよいでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

---

追記です。
以下のように、ユーザエージェントを偽装しても同じ警告が出ます。

```
void CMFCApplication2View::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CHtmlView::OnInitialUpdate();

    Navigate2(_T("https://maps.google.co.jp/"), NULL, NULL, _T("User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko "));
}
```

※上記ユーザエージェントは、実際にIE11でユーザエージェント確認サイトにて確認した内容です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CHtmlViewが使用しているWebBrowserコントロールは互換性のため既定でIE7モードで動作します。IE11モードで動作させたい場合は[Browser Emulation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)#browser-emulation)の説明に従いレジストリを設定する必要があります。

---

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` への書き込みは管理者で行う必要があります。`HKEY_CURRENT_USER` であれば通常の権限で書き込み可能です。加えて、`HKEY_CURRENT_USER` は32bit / 64bit共通です。また`CHtmlView`作成前にレジストリ値が書き込まれていれば良いため、プログラム開始時に書き込めば十分です。

Comment: レジストリ「コンピューター\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION」に「名前：MFCApplication2.exe（<-作成したアプリのファイル名）、値：0x00002af9(11001)」を追加し、PC再起動後に試してみましたが、まだ警告が出ております。私のレジストリ操作の理解はあっておりますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

sayuriさんからの情報を元に、以下のレジストリを追加することで、警告が出なくなりました。

コンピューター\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
名前：MFCApplication2.exe（<-作成したアプリのファイル名）、値：0x00002af9(11001)

※64bitマシンでしたので、
　「コンピューター\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\～」ではなく
　「コンピューター\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\～」に
　追加する必要がありました。

ありがとうございました。

Comment: 補足事項があったため、私の回答に加筆しましたので確認ください。

Comment: 補足ありがとうございます。レジストリについて勉強になりました！